# Open child browser window from child window

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know how to open a browser window from a child window?

On my main window I'm doing a window.open(.....).  But then from this child window I want to open another child window, but its not working.  I mean the problem is that the window opens on the first child.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you giving it a new name?  If you use the same name I believe it opens in the same window.  But if you show code it will be easier to get help.

Comment: Hey I think you are correct.  I'm not passing the name.

window.open("http/localhost/....",null,"width=400,height=400");

I will try giving it a name.... thanks.

Comment: Yup that did the job. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use a different name for each window you open:

```
window.open('url here', 'window one', 'settings')
window.open('url here', 'window two', 'settings')
window.open('url here', 'window three', 'settings')
// and so on
```