# How to open a new popup from a popup page

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open child browser window from child window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813561/open-child-browser-window-from-child-window)

I have a list of all customers contracted with our company!
clicking on the "Contract Details" on the page, a popup opens with details about contractes we have had with him. Clicking on the "Payment Details" button I expect it to to open details about the payment in a new popup but i dont get it.

Anyone know a solution for that?

Comment: Could you post any code? It would work if you define two different `window.open` sentences.

Comment: Look here: [Open child browser window from child window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813561/open-child-browser-window-from-child-window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trythis

```
window.open('your_url','child','height='500',width='500');
```

OR

```
window.open('your_url','mychild','height='500',width='500');
```