# Angular component in a Browser's child window

Tags: angular, browser, components, angular6, childwindow

From an Angular application is there any way that I can create a Browser's child window and show some predefined angular component in it.

**Clarification** : I am not looking for a Modal dialog solution.

Comment: i am not getting you what is child window stand for?

Comment: @R.Viral .. Browser's child window.

Comment: Do you mean with `window.open` ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296704/angular2-how-to-call-component-function-from-outside-the-app/39280942#39280942

Comment: Are you talking about loading a component into an iframe?

Comment: Does this not work? :`<a target="_blank" routerLink="/SomeValidRoute">`

Comment: @dmcgrandle I have already suggested this answer below

Comment: @Shrikey, did you solve this issue?  Specifically as asked, an Angular Component(only - not entire app with instance) in a Browser's Child Window??  Looking to replicate how google's chat pops out from gmail inbox page.

Comment: i have published an angular library, npm package, that does what you need - "popout any part of your Angular application into a new un-docked browser child window"

check it out - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-popout-window

Answer (score 12):

I landed on this post before, so in case someone still trying to render a component dynamically loaded on a different window without running a new app, this is how I did it:

```
export class ChildLoaderComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private r: ComponentFactoryResolver, private 
                           viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
  public windowReference: any;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      //create the component dynamically
      const factory = this.r.resolveComponentFactory(AChildComponent);
      const comp: ComponentRef<AChildComponent> =
        this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
      //in case you also need to inject an input to the child, 
      //like the windows reference 
      comp.instance.someInputField = this.windowReference.document.body;
      //add you freshly baked component on the windows
      this.windowReference.document.body.appendChild(comp.location.nativeElement);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //create the windows and save the reference     
    this.windowReference = window.open('', '_blank', 'toolbar=0, width=800, height=400');
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Sometimes, the easiest old school solutions like these are my favorite. Totally forgot about accessing the body of the new window/tab.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I was looking for a way to open an Angular component in a new window, without bootstrapping the whole app again. We are using this to show a page with manuals and we don't want to open the entire app 2 times.

Comment: This works in chrome/edge/ff but not in ie11. Throws an ERROR HierarchyRequestError

Comment: using this approach the window will open but without the proper css

Comment: I lost all my layout and styling

Comment: how to handle the css on the component. I used this approach its working perfectly fine for component. but its not rendering css properly. can anyone give suggestion on how to render the css.

Comment: this was a long time ago, but have you guys tried something like this to solve styles:

`document.querySelectorAll('link, style').forEach((htmlElement) => {
 if (this.windowReference) {     
        ​this.windowReference.document.head.appendChild(htmlElement.cloneNode(true));
 }
});`

so you can append your styles into the windows and they should load.

Answer (score 8):

This is what i have found for myself, and does exactly what you need.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window

It is possible to show your custom angular components in the new child window, and any angular services will also be injected in any component that is shown in the child window.

It defines a new `WindowComponent`, which contains a portal host. This portal host is attached to the body of the child window. This means that any portals attached to the portal host will be rendered to the body of the child window. To the portal host is passes the `componentFactoryResolver`, the `applicationRef` and the `injector`, presumably so that it can initialize your custom angular components and inject the required services inside the child window.

```
const host = new DomPortalHost(
    this.externalWindow.document.body,
    this.componentFactoryResolver,
    this.applicationRef,
    this.injector
);
```

---

In the template of the `WindowComponent`, it defines a portal using `*cdkPortal`. Inside the portal, it projects the window component's content, as defined by the parent of the window content, using `ng-content`.

```
<ng-container *cdkPortal>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-container>
```

---

Whenever the `WindowComponent` is created, it will open a child window, and attach its portal to the portal host. When the `WindowComponent` is destroyed, it will close the child window.

```
  ngOnInit(){
    // STEP 4: create an external window
    this.externalWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200');

    // STEP 5: create a PortalHost with the body of the new window document    
    const host = ...

    // STEP 6: Attach the portal
    host.attach(this.portal);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    // STEP 7: close the window when this component destroyed
    this.externalWindow.close()
  }
```

---

This means that in the application component you can simply toggle the popup using the `*ngIf` directive on your window component, and nest any content you want to show in the template.

```
<window *ngIf="showPortal">
  <h2>Hello world from another window!!</h2>
  <button (click)="this.showPortal = false">Close me!</button>
</window>
```

---

Using the @angular/cdk package you could also modify this example to create a child window programmatically, by using a `ComponentPortal` instead of retrieving a `CdkPortal` with the `@ViewChild` decorator. By retrieving a reference to the portal host, you can even programmatically replace content of the child window with a different component. When attaching a portal to a portal host, you can also get a `ComponentRef` for your instantiated component, allowing you to interact with it from code.

Comment: This seems like a very clean and good solution, but I run into the following problems:
1. none of the CSS styling is applied in the new window. Not even the app wide style stuff.
2. If I open a modular popup inside of the new Browser-popup the modular popup is opened in the original browser window. I use MatDialog for the modular popups.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried your solution, but when I close popup window and click open me again, it is not shown?

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work in Microsoft Edge browser.

Comment: This is a very nice solution but doesn't work in ie11

Comment: how you handling styles ?

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using `window.open` for the child window in order to
show an angular component that window should load a `website` which
uses angular this means you eighter create in your own app a child
route special for that page and you open your own app to that specific
route. If you chose this solution be aware of the size of your app
this solution works fine if you use async routing so when you open the
app on a new window you will download `angular` + `other core libs`
which you are using and + `js for that specific route`.

Another option is that in your server you create another angular app
with only that content and you have 2 apps on the same server served
at different url's in that case you need to create a new angular app
which contains only that specific content

Comment: I cannot create another angular app. What i want is to show the existing angular "component" in a new window as a "popup" so that it can be in a separate window with all the functionality.

Comment: Hmm so if I understand correctly you want to have a link which opens a new browser window with the same app but in your app you have a dialog opened and that dialog contains your component ?

Comment: Uhmm.. I have a link for **every** component in my app. If i click on it, that particular component should be opened in a child window. Is it still unclear :(

Comment: In case you want that depending on what packages you use you might have the solution for it, so `angular-material` has a [`dialog`](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) component which let's you open a component in a dialog, But that component is not bound to routing if you need to be able to access the dialog using the url you could use `angular` named outlets and have a separate route for the dialog then you use the router to open the dialog here is an [example](https://netbasal.com/give-your-modals-url-address-with-auxiliary-routes-in-angular-eb76497c0bca)

Comment: Let me know if the answer helps so I can update the main answer

Comment: :) I mentioned in the question that i am not looking for the modal approach :)

Comment: Than why don't you add a separate route for your component and just use `window.open(`myAppUrl/urlToMyComponent`)` ? from what I find on the internet that is a browser child [window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813561/open-child-browser-window-from-child-window) eighter I don't understand the term at all

Comment: [@Nicu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3497559/nicu) - I presume because your last suggestion would create a new app instance in the child window requiring SPA to boot up..  No just a component.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using a link with the `target="_blank"` attribute

**example.component.html**

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/route-to-your-component']" target="_blank">
  Open the component in a new tab
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try giving names to your different windows. This will open each new window with the specified name.

```
window.open('url', 'window 1', '');
window.open('url', 'window 2', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Create lazy load component (as url) and put your url in

```
window.open('url', 'window name', 'settings')
```