# How can i open child window from angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, childwindow

I am creating an angular application.

In that, I want to open the child window. and also want to do communication between parent and child browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular component in a Browser's child window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53646015/angular-component-in-a-browsers-child-window)

Comment: i have published an angular library, npm package, that does what you need - "popout any part of your Angular application into a new un-docked browser child window"

check it out - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-popout-window

Answer (score 3):

Try to this:

```
window.open('url', '200', '200');
```

another way

```
<a [routerLink]="['/your-component']" target="_blank">
```

Open other component in new tab.

Comment: let childWindowRefernece = window.open('url', '200', '200');  to handle or close child window from parent window